# Bypassing Windows authentication for SSRS using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, cmd

I want to access SSRS web app. from my windows application. If I accessed report server url from internet explorer and save windows authentication credentials, windows application works. but if i don't authenticate from browser before running windows application it won't.

So How do I Authenticate before running windows application.

here is the SS for authentication window.[SEE image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgOfI.png)

Comment: when making the HTTP webrequest from windows application, set its 'Credentials' property with the username and password you save in browser.

Comment: it's not web request. i want to access the credentials in whole system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for time but i have solved issue
I tried this code to authenticate.

```
 Uri uri = new Uri("http://ReportServer/Reports");
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        //client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        using (Stream data = client.OpenRead(uri))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
            {
                string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
```

And it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get authentication to work by connecting to a service account (so, a user on the report server) like this:

```
HttpClientConnection100 conn = (HttpClientConnection100)Dts.Connections["HTTP Connection Manager"].AcquireConnection(null);  //get connection from connection manager        
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(conn.ServerUserName, conn.GetServerPassword());               //get credentials from Connection manager
```

This is from SSIS and the code I used is deprecated, but if it works, it works...